# Read different streams separately

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, channel

I need to open a multi-channel audio file (two or more microphones) and record the audio of each of them on a different file. With PyAudio I know how to open a multi-channel file (open method) and stop when 1.5 seconds of silence are recorded, but eventually I end up with a single (multi-channel) file. I would like to work live on each of input channels separately: record them on a separate file when a pause is detected. For instance if channel 1 has a silence after 5 seconds I stop its recording on a file, while I keep on recording channel 2 until a silence on that channel is detected as well (e.g., after 10 seconds). Could anyone tell me if this is possible with PyAudio, or point me to the right (Python) library if not?

Comment: did u found any answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not very elegant, but it does work. Open separate streams with the appropriate input_device_index for each.

stream1 = audio.open(input_device_index = 1 ...)

stream2 = audio.open(input_device_index = 2 ...)